# Show first selected item in the react bootstrap dropdown button

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, dropdown, react-bootstrap

I want to display the dropdown with the first item selected when the page renders.
Instead of that, I can see the title of the dropdown. How can I show the first item from the list.

the array list is taking time to load, Is there any way towait and when the value is available  and display it?

```
  const [selectedElement, setSelectedElement] = useState(
    list.length != 0 ? list[0].name : ''
  );

  const handleSelect = e => {
    setSelectedElement(e);
    console.log('cdets--' + cdetsValue);
  };

        <DropdownButton
          id="dropdown-basic-button"
          variant="info"
          className="floatRight"
          onSelect={handleSelect}
          title={selectedElement}
        >
          {list.map((value, i) => {
            return (
              <Dropdown.Item key={i} eventKey={value.name}>
                {value.name}
              </Dropdown.Item>
            );
          })}
        </DropdownButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are using dropdown as select. You can use select for this purpose but as you asked for dropdown I have attached the code below.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { DropdownButton, Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./styles.css";

const list = [
  { key: "Yellow", value: "yellow" },
  { key: "Blue", value: "blue" },
  { key: "Green", value: "green" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});
  const handleSelect = (key, event) => {
    setSelected({ key, value: event.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <DropdownButton
        id="dropdown-basic-button"
        variant="info"
        className="floatRight"
        onSelect={handleSelect}
        title={selected?.key || list[0].key}
      >
        {list.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <Dropdown.Item key={index} eventKey={item.key}>
              {item.value}
            </Dropdown.Item>
          );
        })}
      </DropdownButton>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I guess this will work just the small issue is my list is taking some time to load so its empty when the page loads. Is there any way to wait till the variable has some value?

Comment: As it is default behavior of react, you can hide element until the list is loading by simply check if **selected** has some value or not or **list** is empty or not. You can show **Loading...** in dropdown Button title too.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an active prop to the Dropdown.Item like this :

```
   <DropdownButton
      id="dropdown-basic-button"
      variant="info"
      className="floatRight"
      onSelect={handleSelect}
      title="Select list"
    >
      {list.map((value, i) => {
        return (
          <Dropdown.Item active={i === 0 ? true : false} key={i} eventKey={value.name}>
            {value.name}
          </Dropdown.Item>
        );
      })}
    </DropdownButton>
```

The condition is basically if the item index is 0 which is the first item then it will be active and selected .

Comment: It didnt work. Infact the selected item from the list doesn't show up on the dropdown title too. I want to show the first item from the list as the dropdown title.

Comment: @XXDebugger I need see where and what is the list array that you are mapping .

Comment: My list array has 3 items and if there is a title then the text on the dropdown doesn't change.

Comment: @XXDebugger You need to ask another question about why title then the text on the dropdown doesn't change and provide more of your code so I can help you with . please accept this answer if it helped you in anyway